# Enabling Form Field using checked attribute on custom-switch

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been struggling to make this as reusable as possible. I have written it such that if I put the id's of both the target fieldset and the input checkbox it works. However, I have a number of form elements that must all act the same, so this isn't a great way to deal with it.

When a user enables or disables the checkbox switch, then I want the following form field to disable or enable accordingly. I've tried multiple different ways to accomplish this and cleaned up my javascript based on suggestions in other threads, but when I attempt to activate the switch I get the below error. Any help would be amazing!

> form_enable.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null at enable_disable (form_enable.js:2) at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Trim.htm:11)

My trimmed down HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>       
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="report_url_active" id="report_url_active_yes" onchange="enable_disable(report_url_disable_fieldset,report_url_active_yes)">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="report_url_active_yes">Will you need a report?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <fieldset disabled id="report_url_disable_fieldset"> <!-- Enable if report_url_active_yes is checked -->
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="report_url">Reports URL</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="report_url">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form_enable.js"></script>
</body>
```

And my form_enable.js file:

```
function enable_disable(target_id,check_id) {
document.getElementById(target_id).disabled = !check_id.checked;
}
```

Comment: `onchange="enable_disable('report_url_disable_fieldset','report_url_active_yes')"`

Comment: That removes the error and releases the follow form, but if I disable the switch again it keeps the field enabled <edited to remove stupid sentences...>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>       
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group custom-control custom-switch">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="report_url_active" id="report_url_active_yes">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="report_url_active_yes">Will you need a report?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <fieldset id="report_url_disable_fieldset"> <!-- Enable if report_url_active_yes is checked -->
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="report_url">Reports URL</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="report_url">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form_enable.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `form_enable.js`:

```
document.getElementById("report_url").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
document.getElementById("report_url_active_yes").addEventListener("change", function() {
document.getElementById("report_url_active_yes").checked ? document.getElementById("report_url").removeAttribute("disabled") : document.getElementById("report_url").setAttribute("disabled", "true")
});
```